# Spring Gemfire Cache implementation

Tags: spring, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I am trying to implement cache mechanism provide by *Spring Data GemFire*. Has anyone implemented a solution?  I need to check on performance and ease to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Sonal-

1. First, you can find plenty of examples in the ***Spring* User Guides**, [here](https://spring.io/guides), for example...

   - [Accessing Data with GemFire](http://Accessing%20Data%20with%20GemFire),
   - [Caching Data with GemFire](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching-gemfire/), and ...
   - [Accessing GemFire Data with REST](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-gemfire-data-rest/)
2. Additionally, there is a **Spring GemFire Examples** project [here](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-examples).
3. I have also started work on building a "*Reference Implementation*" (RI) for Spring Data GemFire/Geode, [here](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application).  I have much work to do with this project yet, like documentation (READMEs) in the Repo, but I do plan to keep it up-to-date with my latest developments since I use the code as a basis for all my conference talks.  Anyway, there is plenty of code examples and tests in this GitHub project to keep you busy for awhile.
4. Then, the [*Spring Data GemFire*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire) and [*Spring Data Geode*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode) GitHub projects themselves, have plenty of **tests** to show you how to address different application concerns (Configuration, Data Access, Function Execution, etc, etc).

Of particular interests might be the new *Annotation-based configuration model* for SDG^2 that I am working on.  This is currently a WIP and I am also working on [User Guide documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/) for this feature/functionality, but it is established and even inspired by the auto-configuration features and Annotations provided by *Spring* and *Spring Boot* (e.g. `@EnableXYZ`).

Users have even started using the Annotation-based configuration model without significant documentation in place since it builds on concepts already available and familiar in *Spring Boot*.  In fact combining these SDG specific Annotations with *Spring Boot* makes for a very powerful combination while preserving **simple/easy** nature to **get started**, 1 of my primary goals.

Given the lack of documentation yet, you can find more out in the Spring IO blog, where I first blogged about it [here](https://spring.io/blog/2016/10/11/spring-data-geode-1-0-0-apache-geode-incubating-m3-released).  Then I expanded on this article in a [second blog](https://spring.io/blog/2016/11/10/spring-data-geode-1-0-0-incubating-release-released), talking specifically about **security**.

And if you are really curious, you can follow the latest developments of the *Annotation configuration model* in my [testing efforts](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/tree/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation).

5. Finally, of course, as I have already alluded to, as any good developer knows, getting started is as easy following the examples and reviewing *Spring Data GemFire* [Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/) and [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/api/).

Don't forget to [familiarize yourself with Pivotal GemFire](http://gemfire90.docs.pivotal.io/gemfire/getting_started/book_intro.html) as well!  Javadoc [here](http://gemfire-90-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/).

Hope this helps!

-John